# Javascript - Swap Divs on KeyDown

Tags: javascript, html, toggle, swap

I can swap two divs by clicking on a link, as shown in the following code, but how do I swap them by pressing a key?

This is what I have:

```js
function SwapDivs(div1, div2) {
        d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
        d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
        if (d2.style.display == "none") {
            d1.style.display = "none";
            d2.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            d1.style.display = "block";
            d2.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

```html
<p>
    <a href="javascript:SwapDivs('FirstDiv','SecondDiv')">Swap Divs</a>
</p>


<div id="FirstDiv" style="display:block">
    <p>
        This div is displayed when the page opens.
    </p>
</div>

<div id="SecondDiv" style="display:none">
    <p>
        This div is displayed when the link is clicked.
    </p>
</div>
```

I have used OnKeyDown before, but I can't figure out how to apply it here...

This just doesn't work:

```js
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 32) {
            function SwapDivs(div1, div2);
        }
    });
```

Comment: shouldn't you be calling `SwapDivs` with the parameters 'FirstDiv' and 'SecondDiv', as you did for the working example with the link?

Comment: I tried this:

document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 32) {
            SwapDivs(div1, div2);
        }
    });

But it still doesn't work...

Comment: I think you missed the key point of my comment. Try this: `ocument.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) { if (event.keyCode === 32) { SwapDivs('FirstDiv', 'SecondDiv'); } });`

Comment: Solved it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you call a Function you don't write the "function" keyword before it.
2. You passed two non-existent Variables called `div1` and `div2` in the function `SwapDivs` which was called inside the event listener.
3. If you are adding an Event Listener to the body, you have to add the `<body>` tag.

As an example I used "Arrow Down Key" which has the keycode 40.

```js
    document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 40) {
           SwapDivs('FirstDiv','SecondDiv');
        }
    });
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MqZomW

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work for me. I tried on the page you linked to, and I also tried to copy and paste the code and open it with Firefox, Chrome and IE. The links still works, but when I press the space key, nothing happens... What do you think might be the problem?

Comment: It does work with the down arrow key. I changed the key code to 32 (space) and it started working. Thank you very much, for your help!